# How to Consume Windchill API in asp.net mvc application

Tags: ptc-windchill

I need to consume the WindChill API in a Asp.Net MVC application for some Basic operations of CRUD , or a HTTP get and Post operations samples.

Can some one please assist.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to call windchill API's from ASP.net applications

1. Windchill REST API's (REST Easy) - [PDF having details](https://community.ptc.com/sejnu66972/attachments/sejnu66972/Windchill/28805/1/REST%20Services%20in%20Windchill.pdf)
2. Windchill ODATA based REST API's - [Windchill Help Center Link](http://support.ptc.com/help/windchill/whc/whc_en/index.html#page/Windchill_Help_Center/NewandChanged_REST_Odata.html)
3. Windchill SOAP based webservices - [SOAP approach using Info*Engine](http://support.ptc.com/help/windchill/whc/whc_en/index.html#page/Windchill_Help_Center/IEUG_ArchInteractIE_SimpleObjectAccessProtocolSOAPAppl.html)
4. Windchill Info*Engine tasks ( RMI calls )

Hope this help... you can find more information on https://www.windchillguru.com on windchill technical contents.

Comment: Is Querying the database directly not recommended then?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to invoke Windchill APIs from ASP.NET

1. Write `SOAP\REST` service to expose `Windchill API` and then consume these services using `.NET` code. REST is supported starting from `Windchill 10.2 M030` onwards.
2. Write native code and invoke `java` `APIs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn much about the REST API by playing with the Swagger page at 
https:///Windchill/netmarkets/jsp/restapi/#/Objects/getDisplayableAttributesForType

Note that the REST API comprises mostly GET calls, not many POST calls, and is deprecated. You are best to work with the Odata API (using a recent version of Windchill) at 
https:///Windchill/servlet/odata/v1/IE/$metadata . Cut and Paste this into your browser address bar to explore, or use Postman, PostWoman, CURL, WGET, etc etc.
Leave out the 'v1' version to get the most recent version. Leave out the 'IE' to see all the available endpoints.

Install a recent version of Windchill Rest Services (WRS 1.5, WRS 1.6 etc) for best results. If one of the endpoints is not working, the PTC community recommends installing WRS manually.

HTH -- Rick